# read a text file display result in console without delimeter

Tags: java

I would like to read a csv file and print the result in command line as seperated data without , delimetire.

for ex csv file has data
PVT Ltd, computer department, 5 Employees

```
That needs to be displayed in command prompt as
PVT Ltd
computer department
5 Employees
```

right now I have code as

```
try{
    File myFile=new File("CSV-to-ArayList.csv");
    FileReader fileReader=new FileReader(myFile);

    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String line=null;

    while((line= reader.readLine())!= null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this one prints result as it is like csv file
PVT Ltd, computer department, 5 Employees

please help how would I achieve the result i want.

Comment: Have you tried using proper CSV parser?

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 options which you can read about and experiment with:

1. Using `java.util.Scanner`
2. Using `String.split()` function
3. Using 3rd Party libraries like *OpenCSV*

And here is some code for you:
http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/27/parse-csv-files-in-java/

It's a nice example to experiment with basic java concepts.
I hope you do use this to gain knowledge and basic how-to.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by separator and then join with a new separator, like a space or a new line:

So instead of:

```
while((line= reader.readLine())!= null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

You can do:

```
while((line= reader.readLine())!= null){
    System.out.println(line.split(",").join("\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only seperator should be the "," You could first read in the whole file, and then split them into an String[], which you could then easily display line by line, or do other operations with. This would be my code:

```
try {
        File myFile = new File("est.csv");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(myFile);
        String result;
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
            String line;
            result = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result = result.concat(line);
            }
        }
        String[] items = result.split(",\\s*");
        for (String item : items) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The "\s*" is regex for any spaces between the items.